# File name is generating as "Application.log.1" on reaching maxFileSize

Tags: log4j

below is Log4J.properties configuration ( Using jar "log4j-1.2.17.jar")

```
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c%m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=log\\Application.log
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

but once maxFileSize is reached backup log file is generated as  Application.log.1

I want file to be generated as Application1.log

I got the solution using RollingFileAppender.

```
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.dest1.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.dest1.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=100
log4j.appender.dest1.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=C:\\TRB Workspace\\TRBAutomationFramework\\log\\Application-%i.log
log4j.appender.dest1.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=C:\\TRB Workspace\\TRBAutomationFramework\\log\\Application.log
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

Also required "apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar"

Comment: Have you tried to add a RollingPolicy with a FileNamePattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test, but as explained by Koning, you may try to add this to your properties:

```
log4j.appender.dest1.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.dest1.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.dest1.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=log\\Application-%i.log
log4j.appender.dest1.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=log\\Application.log
```

Comment: You may perhaps ignore the log4j.appender.dest1.triggeringPolicy line, as the maxFileSize is already defined at the appender level.